# Using search bar in safari to search a specific site

Tags: safari, search

One can do searches from the address bar in safari. However one can only specify one search engine to use. Id really like to specify that I want the search to happen in google/youtube/wikipedia etc. Id really like to be able to do searches from the address bar in safari.

I had this in chrome a while back, and I'd love to use it in safari. Does anyone know if an extension is available to do it?

a description of the functionality can be seen in this gif:
https://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2013/09/h2-chrome-omnibox/chromebar_gif_slow_it_down/

Comment: Your question specifies 'search engine' but your requirement would appear to be about a site-specific parameter instead. As wch1zpink has already provided some info on search engines, I've added one on site-specific searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omnikey does this:

Comes as a safari extension, you can download it here:

http://marioestrada.github.io/safari-omnikey/

Comment: It doesn't work now :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same syntax in Safari's address bar as you would directly in Google etc

## site:

**Example**
`iTunes playlist site: apple.stackexchange.com`

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Keyword Search safari extension

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/keyword-search/id1558453954

Comment: the above extension enables you to search a specific site, like enter yt <search-term> and it searches for the term in youtube, isn't that what the author wants

Answer (score 0):

Safari's version of this is "Quick Website Search":

https://appletoolbox.com/safari-quick-website-search-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it/

I haven't figured out how to manually add a new site, however; help welcome!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/344542)

Comment: Also, while the link explains how to enable and disable the functionality, it doesn't explain *how* it can be used/triggered afterwards. Please add these details to your answer.